# UriTemplateTable not distinguishing verbs

Tags: wcf, rest, uritemplate

I have trying to design a REST service in .NET 3.5 with [WCF REST Contrib](http://wcfrestcontrib.codeplex.com). My service is nearly working fine, but I am facing a bizarre error.

Basically, I have two methods:

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/books?id={identity}", Method = "PUT")]
public string InsertBook(string identity, Book book)
{
 // snipped
}
```

and

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/books?id={identity}", Method = "GET")]
public Books[] ListBooks(string identity)
{
 // snipped
}
```

Yet I am getting the error message at activation time:

System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code Message="UriTemplateTable does not support multiple templates that have equivalent path as template '/books?id={identity}' but have different query strings, where the query strings cannot all be disambiguated via literal values. See the documentation for UriTemplateTable for more detail." Source="System.ServiceModel.Web"

If I rename the second method as `/books2?identity` then it works fine.

Any idea why the `UriTemplateTable` is not distinguishing between verbs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the solution. In the web.config, the binding must be specified as `webHttpBinding` (instead of the default `basicHttpBinding`).

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="Foo.MyService">
      <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Foo.MyService" />
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```